# Sending large emails in MVC Controller silently failing

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-5, smtp, async-await

I have a method in my MVC Controller that sends html-formatted emails via SMTP. Haven't had any problems with it except when I try to send long emails:

```
    public async Task<string> TestLargeEmail()
    {
        var recipes = await _context.RecipesNoIngredients.ToListAsync();
        string longBody = this.RenderRazorViewToString("RecipesNoIngredients", recipes.Take(500).ToList()); //~300k characters
        string shortBody = this.RenderRazorViewToString("RecipesNoIngredients", recipes.Take(300).ToList()); //~150k characters

        var longMsg = new MailMessage("TestFrom@email.com", "TestTo@email.com", "Long Message", longBody) { IsBodyHtml = true };
        var shortMsg = new MailMessage("TestFrom@email.com", "TestTo@email.com", "Short Message", shortBody) { IsBodyHtml = true };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(longMsg); //fails silently over the network, but works when delivering to local file system
            await client.SendMailAsync(shortMsg); //works perfectly
        }

        return "done";
    }
```

Web.Config file:

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="test@test.com">
    <network host="smtp.some.address.com" />
</smtp> // Settings when delivering over network
<smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="test@test.com">    
    <network host="smtp.some.address.com" />
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\\TestEmails" />
</smtp> // Settings when delivering to local file system
```

Maybe worth noting that sending synchronously makes no difference either...

Comment: When you say it "fails silently", how do you know it's failing at all? Do you just never receive the email? If that's the case, there's actually probably a limit on the mail server. Gmail for instance will not deliver any message over 25MB.

Comment: Yes I never the receive the email at all, but I figured it wasn't a file size issue since the email file size is only around 150 kb. Also I was able to send bigger emails without problem when I send it manually via outlook / gmail. Thank you

Comment: It could still be a security issue. Very likely the application is running under an other account. The mail can still be blocked somewhere along the pipeline.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "running under another account"? "Another account" as in an Application Pool Identity in IIS?